# Zigbee controlled signal routing?

Tags: hardware, zigbee, philips-hue, audio

I'm thinking of a possible way to allow Hue Bridge to command simple signal routing.
I find myself rewiring my audio setup a lot and was about to just make a simple passive signal chooser dial box, but because all my other workflows are so smoothly integrated to holistic scripts that set things up and ready for me so I can start working, it would be a big help if I could integrate in the audio signal switches too. To avoid pops, the switching could be set to be done before the actual audio devices and speakers are powered.

At the simplest, a signal chooser is basically an ON/ON switch, sometimes with more positions. Just two positions would already be a big help.
I have seen some documentation where people modify an existing Zigbee device to implement it to their own use (such as, using a fader to make motorized curtains), but because the original isn't really fundamentally altered, the Bridge will still pair normally and see it as the device that it used to be.
But what existing device might be logically any similar to an ON/ON switch? I have an Osram smart socket that is smoothly paired with the Philips Hue Bridge, and while it of course doesn't have the fader parameters, it understands commands ON and OFF. I'm not aware if there's any pairable device that already technically is an ON/ON switch. And I'm thinking, if you wanted to change an ON/OFF device into an ON/ON device, it would require altering of the code, which probably isn't possible or allowed.
Or, would it have to be two ON/OFF devices somehow working in parallel so that whenever the state of one changes, the other one toggles its state to the reverse?

I've never seen any talk about Zigbee controlling analog signals so this is either a very dumb and impossible or a very optimistic but workable idea.

Answer (score 2):

Zigbee can work on analog signals. I have interfaced an LDR sensor to one zigbee and sent the data wirelessly to other zigbee which is connected to the arduino uno. On, uno i received the LDR sensor data and was able to implement it to do according to my project. I'll say you should start there. Integrating audio signals on the other hand require more processing power. i'll suggest you start looking at MCU which have a zigbee inbuilt and start your project there. there are plenty of 8-bit 32-bit MCU are available with zigbee from TI and NXP. Read their datasheet first and see if it fits your use case.

I hope this info will be helpful to you!

Answer (score 2):

A two-way switch needs a simple on-off signal, a four way switch needs two on-off signals at a minimum (of course, you could also use 4 on-off switches for 4 wires, and that would allow two switches to be on at once. You could even link the switching to work so that any powered device is on. This switching (and the analogue aspect) all happens at the far end, there is no transmission of the analogue signal.

So long as you implement your own Zigbee endpoint, you can overload any of the existing commands to select the relevant signal sources (colours for example), or split the fader so you have one device switched for each 25% of the fade range.

Digitally controlled analogue switches are common - just make sure you understand the signal level that you're switching.